# video upload using facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the code that i found and run for uploading videos in Facebook using API.

```
<?php
     $app_id = "******";
     $app_secret = "******";
     $my_url = "http://www.someurl.com/testing/2015/fbtest/4.php";
     $video_title = "video";
     $video_desc = "nothing";
     $page_id = "********"; 

     $code = isset($_REQUEST['code']) ? $_REQUEST['code'] : NULL;

     echo '<html><body>';

    if(empty($code)) {

    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
  . "&scope=publish_actions";
   echo('<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>');
   } else {


  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
  . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
  . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
  . "&code=" . $code;
  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $accounts_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?" .$access_token;
  $response = file_get_contents($accounts_url);

   $resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);
   $accounts = $resp_obj['data'];


   foreach($accounts as $account) {
   if($account['id'] == $page_id) {
     $access_token = $account['access_token'];
     break;
   }
   }


     $post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/" . $page_id . "/videos?"
  . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
  . "&access_token=". $access_token;


   echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "  
   method="POST">';
   echo 'Please choose a file:';
   echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
   echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
   echo '</form>';
 }

   echo '</body></html>';
   ?>`
```

When i ran the code I'm getting error like this.

```
      error": 
     {   
     "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",  
     "type": "OAuthException",       
     "code": 190
     }
```

But when i searched for the answer i saw discussions involving including of access key. I don't know where to change my code or is there any other possible solutions to this error.

Comment: do you have you access token/access key?

Comment: and you placed it correctly and you are shure its valid?

Comment: It's telling you that it is invalid.  maybe it knows what its on about.  Have you double/triple checked it ?  Generate another key to try ?

Comment: where to include the access key?

Comment: Its getting my access key right.. I checked

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you need to have OAuth athentication in your app.
Here is the official page, which explain the protocol:

- http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Additionally, you can also check the oauth 2.0 demos and information for PHP:

- http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: I believe you need an access key and you don't have it. Alas I am not an expert in oauth 2.0, so perhaps the documentation I provided can help you.

Comment: i have the access key but i don't know where to include or modify this code.

Comment: Try using the codes in the demo. Maybe a new way to look at the problem is what you need.